# Mailkit asp.net core. How to use password so it is not showing in my code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I can't seem to save my password elsewhere and use it in my code? How would I go about doing this? I am trying to save it in appsetting.json but I can't get it to send an email. It only works when I hard code my credentials.

```
public IActionResult Contact(ContactViewModel contactViewModel)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
try
{
//instantiate a new MimeMessage 
var message = new MimeMessage();
//Setting the To e-mail address
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("E-mail Recipient Name", 
"randocommando2345@gmail.com"));
//Setting the From e-mail address
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("E-mail From Name", "from@domain.com"));
//E-mail subject 
message.Subject = contactViewModel.typeof_app;
//E-mail message body
message.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
{
Text = "Here is what they need: " + contactViewModel.Comment + " <br /> Message was sent by: \n" + 
contactViewModel.first_name + contactViewModel.last_name + "<br /> E-mail: " + contactViewModel.email
};

//Configure the e-mail
using (var emailClient = new SmtpClient())
{
emailClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
emailClient.Authenticate("emailaccount", "password");
emailClient.Send(message);
emailClient.Disconnect(true);
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
ModelState.Clear();
ViewBag.Message = $" Crap! We have a problem here {ex.Message}";
}
}
return View();
}
```

Comment: You can store it in appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

You can get values from appsettigns.json by injecting `IConfiguration` file into your controller.
My `appsettings.json` looks like this

```
{
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Warning"
}
},
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"Hello": "Hi from appsettings",
"EmailSettings": {
"Email": "example@email.com",
"Password": "Password",
"Port": "5000"
 }
}
```

And My controller look like this

```
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {           
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {           
       var getWholeSection =  _configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings").GetChildren().ToList();
        var singleValue = _configuration.GetValue(typeof(string),"Hello");

        return View();
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Second Method:**
Another Way you could wrap your section into as view model then use it then you have to modify your `startup.cs` class

```
services.Configure<MailSettignsViewModel>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
```

Where `MailSettignsViewModel` is my user defined class

```
public class MailSettignsViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have to inject `IOptions` with my view model like this into my controller

```
private readonly IOptions<MailSettignsViewModel> options;
    public HomeController(IOptions<MailSettignsViewModel> _options)
    {
        options = _options;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
       var getSettigns =  options.Value;           
        return View();
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]